# MVC 5 HTML custom helper with content

Tags: html, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

Is it possible to write a custom html helper that has some content it it's body, similar to BeginForm?

I want to write a helper that displays a section only if the user has a particular role.
Something like:

```
@Html.DisplayForRoles("User, manager")
{
    <div>You're admin or manager</div>
    <div>Other stuff</div>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, yes it is.

What you want is to create an HTML helper extension, there's several good guides out there which I won't reproduce here, such as

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs
or
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/720515/Custom-HTML-Helper-for-MVC-Application

Or were you after more specific help?

Comment: But none of those 2 articles explain how to create a tag helper that can accept HTML content?